# Piping python script print out with sed (removing ansi colors) and writing it to a file

Tags: python, bash, sed, pipe, ansi-colors

I'm trying to both see the colorful print out in my python script and writing it to a file without the ansi colors at the same time.

This seems to working fine for me (only save it to a file):

```
$python3 utils/search.py 'Magnesiumstearat' './PROCESSED/md/tablet/2020-08-04/' | sed $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' > results.txt
```

**I don't see the print - it only writes to the file?**

(Using macOS if it matters - but need it to work on a Linux (raspberry pi) as well)

Comment: yes, it only writes to a file. What is your goal?

Comment: To both see the color print AND write to a file (without the colors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution to be

```
python3 utils/search.py 'Magnesiumstearat' './PROCESSED/md/tablet/2020-08-04/' | tee /dev/stderr |sed $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' > results.txt
```

Thanks @Kusalananda https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528333/390853